# Matlab: how to efficiently compute the distance between pairs of objects?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am really being trapped to find a efficient way to compute Euclidean Distance and identify the indices for building sparse matrix. The codes which I am now using are:

```
X = randi(10,100,5);
[m n] = size(X);
mzmax = m*(m-1) / 2;        % number of non-zero distances
ij = zeros(mzmax, 2);       % initialize matrix with indices
D = zeros(mzmax, n);        % initialize matrix with distances
ll = 0;

for k = 1 : m-1

ll = ll(end) + (1 : m-k);
ij(ll,:) = [repmat(k, m-k, 1) (k+1 : m)']; % indices for sparse matrix
D(ll,:) = repmat(X(k,:), m-k, 1) - X(k+1:m,:); % differences between points

end
```

Is there any way to efficiently identify this `D` ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure to use a sparse matrix to represent a complete graph? As the documentation for `pdist` indicates, you can use the `squareform` function convert the vector returned by `pdist` into a full matrix. If you really must have a sparse matrix type, you can use `sparse(D)`, but it will increase the memory size of the matrix and negatively impact performance. You should also use the `'squaredeuclidean'` metric rather than taking the square root and then squaring again.

Comment: Thank you! The `squareform` has answered to build the sparse matrix, I will be testing the efficiency.

Comment: Hi @beaker, I got another question when using pdist, it would be so many thanks if you could give me some advice. The `pdist(D)` gives the sum of the distance of the multiple dimension, however, I want to get the distance separately. For example I have a data set `S` which is a 10*2 matrix , by using `pdist(S(:,1))` and `pdist(S(:,2))` to get the distance separately, but this seems very inefficient when the data has many dimensions. Is there any alternative way to achieve this more efficient? Thank you.